# Android - Apply texture on bitmap (mask)

Tags: android, design-patterns, bitmap, textures, mask

im trying to fill bitmap with pattern.

pattern
[image: pattern]

shirt
[image: shirt]

This is result what i expect.
[image: Shirt with filled pattern.]

This is what i get with this code:
[image: result img]

Can you tell me, what im doing wrong and if you suggest me some approach.

```java
public  Bitmap applyMask(Context context, int resOriginal, int maskToBeApplied) {

    Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resOriginal);

    int width = original.getWidth();
    int height = original.getHeight();

    // decode mask
    Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), maskToBeApplied);

    // create output bitmap
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // create canvas
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    // draw original (shirt)
    canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);

    // draw mask on shirt
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));

    // draw mask
    canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 300, 400, paint);

    // recycle used bitmaps
    original.recycle();
    mask.recycle();

    return output;
}
```

Comment: @Leonardo , Did you get solution for this ?

Comment: I didn't... I just edited the post, I'm not really an Android expert... @RaviSahu, if an answer to this question is helpful for you, you could start a bounty to raise the attention to the question...